# Read a User stored in a SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I need to get info for a user stored in a SharePoint list, such as title, id, and loginName.

Basically my situation is this: I have an "Organization Contacts" list that includes the Office365Account for a particular user, and a Manager that is associated with that user. Both of these fields are SharePoint "Person" fields.

The code below is my attempt to:

1. Query the list to get the item (row) with an Office365Account that matches the current user.
2. Read the manager field from that item (row).

I know something's wrong with the technique I'm trying because the app freezes up when the line starting with `var managerName` is uncommented. Chrome Dev tools seem to be telling me that all other lines are working, or at least not causing errors, so I expect the issue is with the `var managerName` line.

```
function getManagerNameforModal() {
    var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentContext, hostUrl);
    var hostweb = hostContext.get_web();
    var list = hostweb.get_lists().getByTitle(contactsListName);

    //A caml query to get manager name for the record where user is equal to current user.
    var queryXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Office365Account' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml(queryXml);

    var items = list.getItems(query);
    var managerName = items.get_item["Manager"].get_title(); //This doesn't work.

    currentContext.load(items);
    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(onGetManagerNameSuccess, onGetManagerNameFail);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example contains the following issues/typos :

First, `items` is a [SP.ListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244833%28v=office.15%29.aspx), so in order to get item you could use the following example:

```
for(var i = 0;i < items.get_count();i++) {
    var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i); 
}
```

Second, the appropriate syntax to access [SP.ListItem.item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee549053%28v=office.14%29.aspx) in JSOM is:

```
var managerName = item.get_item("Manager");  //not a square brackets
```

Third, since JSOM is an **async** API, list items collection have to be requested first using `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync` method, and only then you could access it using `successHandler`:

```
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

        for(var i = 0;i < items.get_count();i++) {
            var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i);
            var managerName = item.get_item("Manager");     
        }


    }, 
    function(){
        console.log('Error');
    });
```

Forth, `managerName` is of `SP.FieldUserValue` type that does not contain property `Title`

### Fixed example

```
var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentContext, hostUrl);
var hostweb = hostContext.get_web();
var list = hostweb.get_lists().getByTitle(contactsListName);

//A caml query to get manager name for the record where user is equal to current user.
var queryXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Office365Account' /><Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml(queryXml);

var items = list.getItems(query);

currentContext.load(items);
currentContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){

    for(var i = 0;i < items.get_count();i++) {
        var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i);
        var managerName = item.get_item("Manager").get_lookupValue();     
    }


}, 
function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, good sir. Thanks for the explanation of why my stuff was wrong too, now I understand more about JSOM, lists and stuff.